# Piano - Making video with best audio

Tags: digital-piano

I'm trying to make videos with the best audio.

I have a digital piano that records MIDI and/or audio that I can transfer to my computer to pair with video. I've been using iMovie to pair the two, but in the published piece the audio quality seems to drop.

What is the best way to do this?